# Dagger 2, injectiong UI elements

Tags: android, dagger-2

Is it possible to inject some UI elements such as `AlertDialog` and `ProgressDialog` that needs Activity for initializing? Initializing them with `Application` not working of course and also we cannot create `Singleton` dependency using `Activity` (because of the reference to destroyed activity)

Comment: Aren't you essentially looking for subscoping, such as component dependencies or subcomponents?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Dagger don't differentiate orinary and lifecycle classes, but you should store Dagger component inside Activity or Fragment to avoid memoty leaks. Those instances will be singletons only inside your component.